# Keep table height fixed i.e., inside a block , and also add a scrollview inside my table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `html` table which shows all the records fetched from `mysql` database. This is my table created:

```
<table id="employee_details" border="2"></table>
```

**My css**:

```
#employee_details{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top:15em;
  left:20em;
  width:75em;
}

#employee_details td{
  height:60px;
  text-align: center;
  width:12em;
}
```

Now, in my `javascript`, I create the table rows and cells dynamically, based on the number of records fetched. This is my code snippet:

```
var count=0;
success:function(response){
      const arr = JSON.parse(response);
      table.style.display="block";
      
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

          var row = table.insertRow(count);  
          var cell = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
          var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
      
          //cell.innerHTML = arr[count] for all the rows
          
          count++;
       }
}
```

So, for each response, it creates a row and inserts the values to its appropriate cells. So, the table height is dynamic *(it depends on the number of records fetched)*.

What I want is the table to have a fixed height (inside a block), inside which there will be a vertical scrollbar which you can use to scroll up and down to view all the records. Along with that the first row `table.rows[0]` should be freezed so that it doesn't move along with the scroll *(as it contains the label for each cell)*.

How do I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is that you have to wrap your table inside a div and then use `overflow: auto;` to that div.

Here is the example *https://codepen.io/rk-v/pen/BaRqPoB*

Comment: Is it possible to freeze the first row of the table *(the row that contains **First name**, **Last name** and **Age**)*? So that when I scroll up and down, the first row doesn't move along with it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. you can use `position: sticky;` with the first row but you have to adjust some of the other things along with it. Like you have to apply `position: absolute` for it to work properly.